# Android Bluetooth: Connect()/Disconnect()

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am currently designing an app which needs to connect to a device, write/read data, and close the connection reliably. Currently, I have the write/read solid. My disconnect and then reconnect is terribly unreliable, and often actually crashes the phone and, sometimes, Eclipse.

**CONNECT FUNCTION**

```
public boolean connect()
{
  ConfigData.getInstance();
  BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
  BluetoothDevice device = ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothDevice;
  Method m;
  try {
   
   tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);//(BluetoothSocket)
    m.invoke(device, 1);
  } catch (SecurityException e) { 
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothSocket = tmp;
        try {
   ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothSocket.connect();
   ConfigData.bIsBTConnected = true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
   try {
    closeSocket();
    m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
    tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
   } catch (SecurityException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
   } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothSocket = tmp;
   try {
    ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothSocket.connect();
    ConfigData.bIsBTConnected = true;
   } catch (IOException e1) {
    ConfigData.m_BluetoothException += e1.toString();
    ConfigData.bIsBTConnected = false;
    return false;

   }
   e.printStackTrace();
   return true;
  }
        return true;
 }
```

**Disconnect Function**

```
 public void destroySocket()
 {
     try {
      if(m_InStream != null)
      {
       m_InStream.close();
       m_InStream = null;
      }
      if(m_OutStream != null)
      {
       m_OutStream.close();
       m_OutStream  = null;
      }
      if(ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothSocket != null)
      {
       ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothSocket.close();
       ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothSocket = null;
      }
      if(m_InStream == null && m_OutStream == null && ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothSocket == null)
   {
       ConfigData.bIsBTConnected = false;
   }
  } catch (IOException e1) {
   m_InStream = null;
   m_OutStream  = null;
   ConfigData.m_SharedBluetoothSocket = null;
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

So the disconnect is successful and returns everything `null`. The problem is that when I reconnect it blocks at the 2nd connect attempt and either just sits there or completely crashes the phone, causing several reboots.

Does anyone have any advice here?

Answer (score 0):

What phone are you using? What OS?  See this answer:
[Disconnect a bluetooth socket in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031796/disconnect-a-bluetooth-socket-in-android)

The close is actually not working properly on some HTC 2.1update1 phones

Comment: Okay. I'm using the HTC Incredible 2.1update1 OS.  I saw that post but I also saw that it had been answered and tried those answers and had no positive result.  Do you know if/when the Incredible is supposed to get Froyo?

Thanks though!