# Send command from android mobile to PIC 16F1517 microcontroller via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, microcontroller

I am struggling through one issue which is related to Android, Bluetooth Dongle and PIC micro-controller(16F1517). First i have to connect through my Android device and external Bluetooth dongle. Bluetooth dongle is connected with control Box(PIC micro-controller). Then i have to send some binary command from Android device to PIC micro-controller through Bluetooth. I tried a lot but did not get any luck to get rid this peace of work. I gone through below link

[Question posted by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848343/send-command-to-bluetooth-from-android-device)

[nbCafe link](http://www.nbcafe.in/interfacing-android-with-pic-microcontroller-via-bluetooth/)

Here i have couple of doubts:

- Can i get any library or interface for PIC micro controller through
  which I can communicate from Android device?
- Can i get any code sample for Android, so that i can use it?

Comment: How is the Bluetooth dongle connected to the PIC? What is the Bluetooth dongle that you are using?

Comment: Take a look at this android documentation related to the Bluetooth Serial Port Profile: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html

Comment: Ok i will see it. But are you sure i have issue in Socket side??

Comment: There are many app on the store to communicate with bluetooth devices. see the list: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=bluetooth%20controller&c=apps

Comment: I am not sure which part are you having issue. did you do troubleshooting? i recommend install a bluetooth controller app from the link i posted above and pair with ur dongle and send some command. Then in ur pic code log some outputs to see if BT messages arrive there? maybe it is wiring issue!

Comment: @uguboz.. Thanks for your response.My all effort are mentioned in another link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848343/send-command-to-bluetooth-from-android-device

Comment: It would be great if i am able to get some code. how to connect with PIC MCU and How to send the command? I will check Play store, and lets see what i can get so that get rid this issue.

Comment: to be more specific download https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=softigloo.btcontroller. connect ur BT device and PIC as described in the link http://www.nbcafe.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/pic16f877.jpg. Make sure BT Rx pin connected to PIC Tx and vice versa. PIC code also provided in ur link http://www.nbcafe.in/interfacing-android-with-pic-microcontroller-via-bluetooth/. Just make some modification to print read serial port which is connected to BT. that s it

Comment: Any solution ...... ?