# Difficulties while connecting to remote device. Needs more than one try

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I working with a project where I need to connect my tablet (android 4.2.2) to Bluetooth-to-UART converter (RN42 by microchip).
I am using BluetoothChat example to manage bluetooth connection, but its difficult to connect. Sometimes program fails at method mmSocket.connect(); - it throws IOException. Sometimes i need three or more tries to connect to my remote device. After connection is made, it is very stable.
I tried to change UUID, tried to change rn42 module (i also tried to use HC-05 module).
I tried secure and insecure rfcomm connection, still no luck.
here is my code:
In the MainActivity:

```
  @Override
public void onButtonPressed(View view, Device device){
    switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.buttonRedaguotiIrengini:
        // Edit button is pressed
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DeviceActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("device", device);
        i.putExtra("requestCode", REQUEST_EDIT_DEVICE);
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_EDIT_DEVICE);
        break;
    case R.id.buttonPrisijungti:
        if (mBtService.getState()==BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED){
            mBtService.stop();
        } else {
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getMac());
            mBtService.connect(btDevice, false);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

in the BluetoothService Class:

```
   // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

// Unique UUID for this application
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


// Member fields
private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private final Handler mHandler;
private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

   public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

   private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private String mSocketType;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
        setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            if (D) {Log.d(TAG,  "will try to connect to socket");};
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            if (D) {Log.d(TAG, "failed to connect to socket");};
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                        " socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }
        if (D){Log.d(TAG,  "Success");};
        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

    private void connectionFailed() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(MainActivity.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    if (D){Log.d(TAG,  "Failed, unable to connect device");};
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}
```

Here are the LogCat output

```
  03-12 16:01:38.992: D/mBT(9947): connect to: 00:06:66:67:44:3E
  03-12 16:01:38.992: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(9947): [JSR82] Bluetooth Socket Constructor
  03-12 16:01:38.992: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(9947): [JSR82] type=1 fd=-1 auth=false encrypt=false port=-1
  03-12 16:01:38.993: D/BTSocketService(452): [JSR82][Service] initSocket
  03-12 16:01:38.993: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] initSocketNative +++.
  03-12 16:01:38.993: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] initSocketNative: start to initialize socket.
  03-12 16:01:38.993: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] type=1, auth=0, encrypt=0, port=-1
  03-12 16:01:38.993: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] initSocketNative: Initialize socket done.
  03-12 16:01:38.993: E/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82] alloc context : index=2
  03-12 16:01:38.993: E/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82] Clear context : index=2, ctx.index=0, ctx.fd=0
  03-12 16:01:38.993: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] jsr82ConnectCond (2) initialization success 
  03-12 16:01:38.993: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] jsr82ReadCond (2) initialization success <READ> 
  03-12 16:01:38.993: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] jsr82WriteCond (2) initialization success <WRITE> 
  03-12 16:01:38.993: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] jsr82RegisterCond (2) initialization success <REGISTER> 
  03-12 16:01:38.993: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] initSocketNative ---. fdHandle=32770
  03-12 16:01:38.995: D/mBT(9947): setState() 1 -> 2
  03-12 16:01:38.998: I/mBT(9947): BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:Insecure
  03-12 16:01:39.001: D/BluetoothService(452): [API] cancelDiscovery()
  03-12 16:01:39.001: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [GAP][API] stopDiscoveryNative
  03-12 16:01:39.001: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [GAP] btmtk_gap_discovery_cancel
  03-12 16:01:39.001: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [GAP] btmtk_gap_discovery_cancel already cancelled
  03-12 16:01:39.001: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [GAP] btmtk_gap_send_discovery_stop_event
  03-12 16:01:39.001: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [JNI] bt_sendind(ptr=0x5C6AEA50, len=28)
  03-12 16:01:39.001: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [JNI] send ind=3528
  03-12 16:01:39.001: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] Polling returned
  03-12 16:01:39.001: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] Start retrieve data
  03-12 16:01:39.002: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] fd 1 data ready
  03-12 16:01:39.002: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] nat->pollData[i].fd data ready : revents = 0x1
  03-12 16:01:39.002: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] msg 3528 received : size=28
  03-12 16:01:39.002: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [GAP] receive event=3528
  03-12 16:01:39.002: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [GAP] btmtk_util_update_adapter_property_discovering: is_discovering = 0
  03-12 16:01:39.002: D/BluetoothEventLoop(452): Property Changed: Discovering : false
  03-12 16:01:39.006: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [JNI] send ind success : 28
  03-12 16:01:39.007: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] Start polling
  03-12 16:01:39.008: V/BluetoothEventManager(1562): Received android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
  03-12 16:01:39.011: D/mBT(9947): will try to connect to socket
  03-12 16:01:39.011: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(9947): [JSR82] connect: do SDP
  03-12 16:01:39.012: D/BluetoothService(452): [API] fetchRemoteUuids(00:06:66:67:44:3E)
  03-12 16:01:39.012: V/BluetoothAdapterProperties(452): getObjectPath():MTKBT/dev_
  03-12 16:01:39.012: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [GAP][API] discoverServicesNative : addr=MTKBT/dev_00_06_66_67_44_3E, pattern=00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
  03-12 16:01:39.013: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [GAP] btmtk_gap_service_search_raw_request addr=67443E:66:6, size=19
  03-12 16:01:39.013: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_write: buffer bebcbcc8, len 5
  03-12 16:01:39.013: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [GAP] btmtk_gap_send_sdp_discover_event
  03-12 16:01:39.013: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [JNI] bt_sendind(ptr=0x54B921A0, len=60)
  03-12 16:01:39.013: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [JNI] send ind=3535
  03-12 16:01:39.013: I/BluetoothService.cpp(452): [JNI] send ind success : 60
  03-12 16:01:39.013: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] Polling returned
  03-12 16:01:39.013: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] Start retrieve data
  03-12 16:01:39.013: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] fd 1 data ready
  03-12 16:01:39.014: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] nat->pollData[i].fd data ready : revents = 0x1
  03-12 16:01:39.014: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] msg 3535 received : size=60
  03-12 16:01:39.014: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [GAP] receive event=3535
  03-12 16:01:39.014: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [GAP] receive event ANDROID_EV_SDP_DEVICE_CREATE 0x67443E:0x66:0x6
  03-12 16:01:39.014: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [GAP] pattern (16)  0: 0:11: 1
  03-12 16:01:39.014: I/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(452): [MSG] Start polling
  03-12 16:01:39.015: V/BluetoothDiscoveryReceiver(1562): Received: android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED
  03-12 16:01:39.018: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c901c, len 1
  03-12 16:01:39.018: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c9024, len 2
  03-12 16:01:39.018: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401980e6, len 4
  03-12 16:01:39.018: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c901c, len 1
  03-12 16:01:39.019: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_write: buffer bebcbcc8, len 5
  03-12 16:01:39.026: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c901c, len 1
  03-12 16:01:39.026: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c9024, len 2
  03-12 16:01:39.026: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401981e7, len 4
  03-12 16:01:39.026: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c901c, len 1
  03-12 16:01:39.026: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_write: buffer bebcbcc8, len 17
  03-12 16:01:39.032: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c901c, len 1
  03-12 16:01:39.032: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c9024, len 2
  03-12 16:01:39.032: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401982e8, len 4
  03-12 16:01:39.033: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c901c, len 1
  03-12 16:01:40.017: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c901c, len 1
  03-12 16:01:40.017: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c9024, len 2
  03-12 16:01:40.017: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401983e9, len 4
  03-12 16:01:40.017: D/[BT](142): mtk_bt_read: buffer 401c901c, len 1
  03-12 16:01:44.775: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(692): [BT][HFG] [API] mStateReceiver.onReceive(android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED)
  03-12 16:01:44.776: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(692): [BT][HFG] [API] mHandler.handleMessage(9)
  03-12 16:01:44.776: D/Bluetooth HS/HF(692): [BT][HFG] [API] updateBatteryState
  03-12 16:01:45.014: D/BluetoothService(452): [API] getUuidFromCache(00:06:66:67:44:3E)
  03-12 16:01:45.015: D/BluetoothService(452): [API] getUuidFromCache=00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
  03-12 16:01:45.016: D/BluetoothService(452): [API] getUuidFromCache=00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
  03-12 16:01:45.016: D/BluetoothService(452): [API] sendUuidIntent(00:06:66:67:44:3E)
  03-12 16:01:45.020: D/Bluetooth HSHFP(692): [BT][HFG][Intent] action=android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID, state=0
  03-12 16:01:45.022: D/BluetoothService(452): [API] makeServiceChannelCallbacks(00:06:66:67:44:3E)
  03-12 16:01:45.022: D/BluetoothService(452): Cleaning up failed UUID channel lookup: 00:06:66:67:44:3E 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
  03-12 16:01:45.022: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(9947): [JSR82] SdpHelper::onRfcommChannelFound: channel=-1
  03-12 16:01:45.023: D/mBT(9947): failed to connect to socket
  03-12 16:01:45.023: W/System.err(9947): java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
  03-12 16:01:45.024: W/System.err(9947):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:813)
  03-12 16:01:45.024: W/System.err(9947):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:382)
  03-12 16:01:45.024: W/System.err(9947):   at p.demoui.BluetoothService$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothService.java:389)
  03-12 16:01:45.024: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(9947): [JSR82] close
  03-12 16:01:45.024: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(9947): [JSR82] readLock got.
  03-12 16:01:45.025: D/BTSocketService(452): [JSR82][Service] abort
  03-12 16:01:45.025: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] abortNative +++. fd=32770.
  03-12 16:01:45.025: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] abortNative ---.
  03-12 16:01:45.025: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(9947): [JSR82] Start to aquire writeLock.
  03-12 16:01:45.026: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(9947): [JSR82] writeLock got.
  03-12 16:01:45.026: D/BTSocketService(452): [JSR82][Service] destroy
  03-12 16:01:45.026: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82][JNI] destroyNative: fd=32770.
  03-12 16:01:45.026: E/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(452): [JSR82] Clear context : index=2, ctx.index=-1, ctx.fd=32770
  03-12 16:01:45.030: D/mBT(9947): Failed, unable to connect device
  03-12 16:01:45.030: D/mBT(9947): setState() 2 -> 0
```

Where is mistake? how can I improve this code?
Why is the IOException is thrown in this case?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am also facing this issue.Did you find a solution to it ? Also, you said that once the connection is established between your device and RN42 the connection is strong.Have you tested on how long is this connection maintained? Do you periodically send data on DataOut/DataIn to maintain the bluetooth channel connectivity ?

Comment: Well, I left connected devices for a few hours, and connection was ok. I send data only when the key is pressed (not periodically).
ALso, I noticed that after powering rn42 and restarting my app, connection is made at the firs try. but after i disconnect, its gets difficult to connect again. maybe i miss something when closing connection?

Comment: Hmmm, well I guess only testing over a long period of time will tell if the connection btw your device and RN42 is active,else may be one needs to maintain the connection by sending dummy data periodically(that's what I might end up doing in my project,why take a risk!).As far as your problem of reconnecting is concerned,one thing to understand is that a socket connections needs to be properly closed(along with DataOut and DataIn).This is a process and has to be followed.Check out Brad Hein's ans- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031796/disconnect-a-bluetooth-socket-in-android.

Comment: Also buddy can you tell me which tablet are you using for your testing ? For my testing I am using iball 3G 7271.The funny thing is when I try connecting my samsung S2/grand with RN42,then I can tell that till date the connection has worked flawlessly.I have heard that chinese tablets that have MTK processors(iball being chinese) have some issues related to bluetooth stack ,that can be overcome using reflection - Read this post:http://redacacia.me/2012/07/17/overcoming-android-bluetooth-blues-with-reflection-method/#comment-1414 . It has helped some but not me.

Comment: I updated code and now closing input and output streams before closing socket. also tried to use reflection, but i can't see any improvements  in behaviour.
I am using ASUS MEMO PAD tablet. Before this, i was experimenting with  my phone LG optimus, and basically had the same issues.
Do you get the same IOException while trying to connect to socket?

Comment: Sorry that my suggestions cudn't resolve ur issue.But when I had incorporated those in my code I did see improvement.As I mentioned before my code runs perfectly on my S2/grand,but the same code throws me exceptions on my iball 3G 7271 tablet(chinese made with MTK family).I do get exceptions stating 'Service Discovery Failed','Connection is not created(failed or aborted','Resource is busy' quiet often.I see that your device too uses MTK hardware.Have you tried running your code on another non MTK device like samsung phones? Try it,it should work there.Let me know how it goes.Atb !

Comment: Also do check out dknop's answer(ans no #19,jan28 2011) here:- " https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5427 " .See if it can help you. Let me know if you get a soln.Even I am stuck with this issue for last couple of days.

Comment: Did u find a soln yet? I am still stuck on this issue :(,though I have found the instances at which the exceptions occur.When the app is installed,then connection/disconnection to RN42 happens well with no issues.Now,if the app is connected to RN42 and if I re-install the app,at this stage firstly the BT conn is lost as I have reinstalled,moreover a reconnection attempt to RN42 throws ' Connection is not created (failed or aborted)'.continued...

Comment: continued.. Soln - Reboot tablet OR switch BT off and ON,and retry BT connection with RN42 succeeds.But the prob I now face here is I don't get input signals from RN42 to tablet but I am able to send output signals from tablet to the RN42. I strongly suspect this is something to do with the ports on tablet.For one instance of the app we get the proper ports,but reintallation(while an active BT connection to RN42), and a reconnection to RN42 doesnt give access to the active BT port and throws error.Did you too face issue at similar test cases?

Comment: I also noted that reinstalling app while connected to rn42 couses connection problems and usually you have to restart BT or tablet. Clearly this behavour is not normal - you SHOULD NOT reinstall app while connected to rn42. Also, I have several rn42 devices, and noticed that if I trying to connect them one by one everything works good enough. Problem occur only when i try to reconnect to the same rn42 in short period of time, let say 2 sec.

Comment: what about your problem, can be several different reasons. you should create your own Question and post some code, it would be easier to help you. Let me know when you do that.

Comment: The reason I was testing the BT connection on reinstall is because in my project I may have to remotely update the app on the tablet.As far as re-connecting to the same RN42 is concerned,I tested this and works well for me.I could re-connect-disconnect-reconnect the tablet and RN42 as many no of times.Make sure that everytime you properly disconnect by closing all BT stuffs and then reconnect.You can see my code in the second link in below comment.What is the error you are getting when you try reconnecting in 2sec?

Comment: Yes, buddy I have been trying to find solution to this bug for the last one week,and I'm almost running out of all options..lol.Ans yes,I have already posted my questions on SO - "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378331/android-bluetooth-connect-throwing-error" and, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495044/connection-is-not-created-failed-or-aborted-exception-thrown-during-bluetooth/22497722?noredirect=1#22497722"

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I had done similar Bluetooth connection and sending commands.I am posting complete demo code please give it a try.

**BluetoothService.java** ( same class from BluetoothChat example)
can be found here http://stanford.edu/~tpurtell/BluetoothChatService.java

In My case MacID was already pre given to me.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


        // Layout Views
        private Button bt_on_off;
        private TextView statuses;
        private Button connectIt;

        private Button click;

        //Timer timer;
        private boolean isBTOnOrOff = false;

        // Debugging
        private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
        private static final boolean D = true;

        // Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
        public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
        public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
        public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
        public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

        // Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
        public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
        public static final String TOAST = "toast";

        // Intent request codes
        private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
        private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

        // Name of the connected device
        private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
        // Array adapter for the conversation thread
        //private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
        // String buffer for outgoing messages
        private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
        // Local Bluetooth adapter
        private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
        // Member object for the chat services
        private BluetoothService mChatService = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initViews();
            enableDissableViews(false);
            listeners();

            preBTConfigCheck();
        }

        private void initViews() {

            bt_on_off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_on_off);
            connectIt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
            statuses= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statuses);

            click= (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);

        }

        private void listeners() {
            bt_on_off.setOnClickListener(this);
            connectIt.setOnClickListener(this);
            click.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        // Broadcast reciever for BT
        private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                final String action = intent.getAction();

                if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                    final int state = intent.getIntExtra(
                            BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                    switch (state) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        enableDissableViews(false);
                        isBTOnOrOff=false;
                        bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.on_off_status)
                                + "OFF");
                        if (D)
                            Log.d(TAG, "STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        enableDissableViews(false);
                        bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.on_off_status)
                                + "Turning off...");
                        if (D)
                            Log.d(TAG, "STATE Turning off...");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.on_off_status)
                                + "ON");
                        if (D)
                            Log.d(TAG, "STATE ON");
                        enableDissableViews(true);
                        isBTOnOrOff=true;
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.on_off_status)
                                + "Turning on...");
                        if (D)
                            Log.d(TAG, "STATE Turning on...");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        private void preBTConfigCheck() {

            // Register for broadcasts on BluetoothAdapter state change
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

            // Get local Bluetooth adapter
            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

              // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                // Device does not support Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "BlueTooth Not supported on your device!", 0).show();
                bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.on_off_status)
                        + "NOT SUPPORTED");
                enableDissableViews(false);
            } else {
                // status of BT
                isBTOnOrOff = mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
                if (D)
                    Log.d(TAG, "BT status @ preBTConfigCheck() ->" + isBTOnOrOff);
                if (isBTOnOrOff) {
                    // Bluetooth is enable,
                    bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.on_off_status)
                            + "ON");
                    enableDissableViews(isBTOnOrOff);
                } else {
                    bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.on_off_status)
                            + "OFF");
                    // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                    if (D)
                        Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                    enableDissableViews(isBTOnOrOff);
                }
            }
        }


         @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

                // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
                // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                // Otherwise, setup the chat session
                } else {
                    if (mChatService == null) setupCommand();
                }
            }
         @Override
            public synchronized void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");

                // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
                // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
                // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
                if (mChatService != null) {
                    // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
                    if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothService.STATE_NONE) {
                      // Start the Bluetooth chat services
                      mChatService.start();
                    }
                }
            }


         @Override
            public synchronized void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
                if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
                this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
                if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
            }

         private void setupCommand() {
                Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

                // Initialize the BluetoothService to perform bluetooth connections
                mChatService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler);

                // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
                mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            }
        private void resultMacId(String address) {


              // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
            // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
            // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
            if (mChatService != null) {
                // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
                if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothService.STATE_NONE) {
                  // Start the Bluetooth chat services
                  mChatService.start();
                }
            }
            // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

            // Attempt to connect to the device
            mChatService.connect(device, false);
        }
          @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }
         @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
            {
                switch (item.getItemId()) 
                {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
        private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);



                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        statuses.setText("connected to :"+mConnectedDeviceName);
                       // mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                        //mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName);
                        //mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();

                        break;
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        statuses.setText("connecting ... ");

                       // mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);

                        break;
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case BluetoothService.STATE_NONE:
                        statuses.setText("Not Connected");
                       // mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the buffer
                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    Log.d(TAG, "MESSAGE_WRITE++++++++"+writeMessage);
                    //mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    Log.d(TAG, "MESSAGE_READ++++++++"+readMessage);

                   // mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    // save the connected device's name
                    mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);

                    statuses.setText("Connected to "+ mConnectedDeviceName);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                                   + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    connectIt.setText("Connected to "+ mConnectedDeviceName);
                    connectIt.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    statuses.setText(msg.getData().getString(TOAST));

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };


        /**
         * Sends a message.
         * @param message  A string of text to send.
         */
        private void sendMessage(byte[] message) {
            // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
             if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "not_connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } 

            // Check that there's actually something to send
            if (message.length > 0) {
                // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write

                mChatService.write(message);

                // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
                //mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
                 //mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
            }
        }
        private void btOnOffClick() {

            if (D)
                Log.d(TAG, "BT status @ btOnOffClick() ->" + isBTOnOrOff);
            if (isBTOnOrOff) {
                // make BT off & set isBTOnOrOff to false
                btOFF();
                isBTOnOrOff = false;

            } else if (!isBTOnOrOff) {
                // make BT on & set isBTOnOrOff to true

                btON(REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                isBTOnOrOff = true;
            }

        }

        private void btOFF() {
            enableDissableViews(false);
            if (D)
                Log.d(TAG, "BT status @ btOFF() -> OFF");

            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.on_off_status)
                    + "OFF");
        }

        private void btON(int requestType) {
            if (D)
                Log.d(TAG, "BT status @ btON() -> Turning on dialog");

            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, requestType);

        }
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (D)
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
            switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Bluetooth is now enabled,
                    isBTOnOrOff=true;
                    enableDissableViews(true);
                    bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.on_off_status)
                            + "ON");
                    if (D)
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult - status ON ");
                } else {
                    isBTOnOrOff=false;
                    enableDissableViews(false);
                    bt_on_off.setText(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.on_off_status)
                            + "OFF");
                    if (D)
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult - BT not enabled");
                    // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bt_on_off:
                if (D)
                    Log.d(TAG, "...........ON OFF button clicked ........ ");
                // check for BT adaptor available then check its on or off
                try {
                    if (D)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Before sleep");
                    // Thread.sleep(SLEEP_THREAD_FOR_ACTION);
                    if (D)
                        Log.d(TAG, "after sleep");
                    btOnOffClick();
                    if (D)
                        Log.d(TAG, "after btn click completed");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
            case R.id.connect:
                resultMacId("00:08:F4:00:12:A4");
                break;
            case R.id.click:
                sendMessage("commands in bytes".getBytes());
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }


        private void disconnectIt() {
             if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
             connectIt.setEnabled(true);
        }


        void enableDissableViews(boolean state)
        {   
            if (!state) {
                connectIt.setText("Not Connected");
            }
              connectIt.setEnabled(state);
        }

    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#bababa"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_on_off"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/on_off_status" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statuses"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/all_status"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/socket_connected_status" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="GPS"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/click"
            android:layout_width="317dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```