# Android Kotlin - How can I programmatically disconnect a bluetooth device?

Tags: android, kotlin

Right now I have a code that connects the phone to a bluetooth printer, the problem is that I want to close that connection while not needing it, in other words I just want the device to connect to the printer when it needs to send a file and I want it to then disconnect.
To connect to the printer I'm using the following code:

```
fun connectBluetooth(address: String): Boolean {
        var connectSuccess = true

        try {
            if (bluetoothSocket == null) {
                val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
                val device: BluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter!!.getRemoteDevice(address)
                bluetoothSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID)

                bluetoothSocket!!.connect()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            connectSuccess = false
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return connectSuccess
    }
```

I'm wondering how I can then close the connection, right now I have been simply doing

```
bluetoothSocket = null
```

but I highly doubt that is the right way to do it

Comment: you want to unpair the device ?

Comment: not unpair but simply close the connection

Comment: disable bluethooth adapter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031796/disconnect-a-bluetooth-socket-in-android kindly refer this link , its might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it wasn't as hard as I thought it would be, all that had to be done was to close the output stream that I was using in order to send the file to the printer.

I found out about this thanks to the link that was refered to me in the comments by vyas dipak: [Disconnect a bluetooth socket in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031796/disconnect-a-bluetooth-socket-in-android)

All I did was create this small function and it all worked out well

```
fun disconnectBluetooth(){
    val outputStream : OutputStream? = null

    try {
        outputStream?.close()
    } catch (e: IOException ){}

    try {
        bluetoothSocket?.close()
    } catch (e: IOException){}

    bluetoothSocket = null
}
```